# SQL dates Overlapping

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have  a following table with data in sql. I wanted to know the dates which are overlapping.

```
ARN NO      From Date   To Date
1   106739  1/1/2015    3/31/2015
2   106739  1/1/2015    2/28/2015
3   106739  3/1/2015    3/31/2015
4   106739  5/1/2015    6/30/2015
5   106739  7/1/2015    9/30/2015
6   106739  9/1/2015    9/30/2015
7   106739  10/1/2015   12/31/2015
8   106739  10/1/2015   12/31/2015
```

In the above table, the first three records are overlapping. How do I write a query to find out? I need the below output

```
   NO  ARN NO   From Date   To Date
   4    106739  5/1/2015    6/30/2015
```

Thanks

Comment: what about the last two? they are overlapping as well.

Comment: Yes. Its overlapping. I edited the question . please see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.arnno = t.arrno and
                    t2.fromdate < t.todate and
                    t2.todate > t.fromdate
             );
```

Two time periods overlap if the first starts before the second ends and ends after the second starts.

Comment: I think there's some confusion at the end of your last sentence. `and ends` - if we insert the intended implied subject, I can't make it work substituting either of `the first` or `the second`.

Comment: You should consider one more value which is unique to the each row. For my case it is payment List ID, which I have not listed down in the question